# python request response (binary)

Tags: python, binary, response

I am trying to do a small project with Python to use TD Ameritrade API. In the API instruction by TD, it says the request URL for PriceHistory is:

https://apis.tdameritrade.com/apps/100/PriceHistory?source=##SourceID#>&startdate=&enddate=&requestvalue=&intervaltype=&periodtype=&extended=&intervalduration=&period=&requestidentifiertype=Of course I need to replace the SourceID with my own SourceID.

And the response according to the manual's example is:

00 00 00 01 00 04 41 4D 54 44 00 00 00 00 02 41
97 33 33 41 99 5C 29 41 90 3D 71 41 91 D7 0A 47
0F C6 14 00 00 01 16 6A E0 68 80 41 93 B4 05 41
97 1E B8 41 90 7A E1 41 96 8F 57 46 E6 2E 80 00
00 01 16 7A 53 7C 80 FF FF

Another table is also attached to interpret the meaning of every number above.

So I wrote my program like this:

```
EOR_url = (the above URL, omitted here)
r = request.get(EOD_url)
print r.content
```

it doesn't print out anything. How can I show or print out the response just like that given in the above table? I believe I still don't quite understand the response object yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

update:

```
EOR_url = (the above URL, omitted here)
r = request.get(EOR_url)
h = binascii.b2a_hex(r.content)
print h
```

now it is printing out results just like that given in the TD API instruction:

00 00 00 01 00 04 41 4D 54 44 00 00 00 00 02 41
97 33 33 41 99 5C 29 41 90 3D 71 41 91 D7 0A 47
0F C6 14 00 00 01 16 6A E0 68 80 41 93 B4 05 41
97 1E B8 41 90 7A E1 41 96 8F 57 46 E6 2E 80 00
00 01 16 7A 53 7C 80 FF FF

The instruction does say:
00 00 00 01, 4 bytes, Symbol Count is 1
00 04, 2 bytes, Symbol Length is 4
41 4D 54 44, 4 bytes, Symbol is AMTD
00, 1 byte, Error code is 0 (OK)
00 00 00 02, 4 bytes, Bar Count is 2
41 97 33 33, 4 bytes, Close is 18.90
41 99 5C 29, 4 bytes, High is 19.17
41 90 3D 71, 4 bytes, Low is 18.03
41 91 D7 0A, 4 bytes, Open is 18.23
47 0F C6 14, 4 bytes, Volume is 3,680,608
......
FF FF, 2 bytes, terminator

so my question now is how to convert response object's content into real numbers according to the instruction?

how to convert result to real numbers?

thanks

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you should verify that the get request actually returns something. You could use Postmaster or Advanced Rest Client to perform the `GET` request and check out the response. I suspect doing this will enlighten what is actually taking place. If you've already done this can you let me know what the response is?

From my experience using the `requests` module, it is pretty reliable in capturing the responses.